# Cloudflare putting my site in an endless refresh loop

Tags: htaccess, cloudflare

This problem does not happen to all site visitors. The best I can tell, random users of Chrome have the issue but my sample size is way too small to believe that it is only Chrome. However, a few people that have the problem with Chrome do not have it with other browsers. It has happened on PCs and Macs.

I had a few reports of the problem, than all of a sudden it started happening to me. I turned off Cloudflare and the problem immediately stopped. Right now I have to keep Cloudflare off, so there is no point to posting the URL.

This is a new site with an SSL cert. In case it's helpful, here's the .htaccess redirects:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

All advice appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to redirect all access from HTTP to HTTPS??

Comment: Under _CloudFlare Settings_, make sure you have _SSL_ set to _Full_ and not the default _Flexible_, since you have an SSL certificate on the origin server. Also, please edit the question to let us know what your `www` record points to in CloudFlare and in your default DNS provider (they should be the same). You might try the first rewrite [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) to help sort out any loop redirects occurring between `www` and `non-www`. Last but not least, make sure you don't have any Page Rules in CloudFlare setup that might result in a loop.